# A more comprehensive function than recordScalar that stores structured data as value instead of storing a double number

Tags: omnet++

One of the most widely used functions for output generation in Omnet++ is recordScalar.

```
virtual void recordScalar (cComponent *component, const char *name, double value, opp_string_map *attributes=nullptr)=0
```

Is there a more comprehensive function than recordScalar that stores structured data as value instead of storing a double number? Or coding it ourselves.
Or coding a similar function to write mentioned outputs in a text file in the format of JSON by that function?

By structured data, I mean struct data type in c++. like this:

```
struct logtype {
int src;
int dest;
int messagescount; // the count of messages transmitted between src and dest and vice versa
};
```

Thanks

Comment: Could you precise what you mean by _structured data_? Could you provide an example of these data?

Comment: According to @JerzyD. comment, I make the question more detailed.

Answer (score 0):

OMNeT++ does not contain ready to use tool for storing complex structures. However, OMNeT++ uses C++ and one can write own method that will store some data to a text file, or to a JSON file, or to any file.

Comment: How can be written own method that will store some data to a text file or JSON format in anywhere of my project or Inet package and be called at anytime of simulation time? I am searching this answer in my question.

Comment: OMNeT++ is a basically a C++ library. Your question is not OMNeT++ specific, but rather C++ specific, i.e. how can I write a function in C++ which writes out structured data. And to that question there are myriads of answers. Use an SQL database (like SQLITE or POSTRGRESQL) or use and XML or JSON library that has  serialization support, or just simply write out your own data structure in a file write.